# How to access RadioButton's value in Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i make a contact form its working well, but i add radio button so i dont know how can i insert it to db?  i am using repeater

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
  RadioButton CokIyi = (RadioButton)rpPollQuestions.FindControl("rbCokIyi");
            RadioButton Iyi = (RadioButton)rpPollQuestions.FindControl("rbIyi");
            RadioButton Orta = (RadioButton)rpPollQuestions.FindControl("rbOrta");
            RadioButton Kotu = (RadioButton)rpPollQuestions.FindControl("rbKotu");

  DataAccesLayer.CustomerForm.PollAnswers_Insert(CokIyi.Text, Iyi.Text, Orta.Text, Kotu.Text);
```

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+get+radio+button+selected+value&oq=asp.net+get+radio+button+selec&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.3688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a 'Text' property use 'Checked', which will allow you to get or set the value of a radio button.

Answer (score -1):

You can set different values for radio buttons with same name,and you can keep that radio button value in Database.

Comment: Judging by the question, OP understands that, what they don't understand is _how_ to do it. I posted a link to google where there are many examples showing how to get the selected radio button value from the form.

Comment: im using repeater so i want to insert radiobutton values into database. pls help me